# Install and configure xampp for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, netbeans, xampp

**Hello!**
I have been trying to get PHP scripts running for 5 days on Ubuntu 14.04. I installed PHP 5.3, apache2 and xampp for these versions. I used Netbeans to create a simple script with phpinfo(), but I get a blank page when I run it in Netbeans. And I get "The requested URL was not found on this server" when I run project which includes more than only index.php project. When I run localhost in browser Xampp page for Ubuntu is loaded.
I used this answer for  apache2 configuration.
I reinstalled it and tried to configure for the 3d time, so I`m desperate. So I would be grateful for any help and tips!

Comment: xampp is just a packaged shipment of APACHE,MARIADB (MYSQL? ),PHP and PERL. If you are installing apache and php as standalone, as you should be on a production server, then you do not in any way require xampp. The packaged shipment is only meant to make it easy and fast to setup development environments and security is not a top priority in this implementation.

Comment: @coderodour Do you mean that I need to install only xampp or only separated PHP and apache?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Frank B has contributed a very helpful tutorial from a very reliable source. You should study it and make it your regular practice of setting up your environment as it is suitable for development (you may need to configure showing errors, etc as they are hidden as to not show to your users) and production.

Comment: Check this [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/281137/550550) thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

Follow this tutorial. ON Linux google for LAMP not XAMPP